# How to prevent the screen from turning on on incoming calls?

Tags: samsung, calls, screen

I carry the phone in my pocket and when I take it out it often accidentally accepts or rejects the call because the screen automatically unlocks on incoming calls? How can I prevent this, preferably *without* setting a password or pattern for incoming calls, as I can do with some apps. Ideally, I'd like to take the phone out of the pocket, press the power button and see exactly the same screen as I usually see on incoming calls, where I can accept or reject the call by just swiping.

The phone is Samsung Galaxy J1 2016, if that is of any help. Android 5.1.1.